# Ember datatables not able to redraw after changing data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, datatables, ember-addon

I am using [ember-datatables](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-datatables) addon which is based on jquery [Datatables](https://datatables.net/). I have created one datatables as per their guidelines.

But I am chaning the data of table after some time and redrawing the table. Redrawing table do not delete previous data.

Here is [Ember twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/2cc8f0daa073fb5d4eef7845244d3fd9?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C) created by me. Also I am adding code below.

**templates/application.hbs**

```
<h1>Please find data table below</h1>
{{outlet}}
{{#data-table id="myTable"}}
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
      <th>Position</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
      <th>Position</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    {{#each data1 as |data|}}
        <tr>
        <td>{{data.name}}</td>
        <td>{{data.salary}}</td>
        <td>{{data.position}}</td>
      </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
{{/data-table}}
```

**routes/application.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function() {
    Ember.run.later(this, function() {
      this.controller.set('data1', [{
        'name': 'John Smith 1',
        'salary': '$2000',
        'position': 'developer'
      }, {
        'name': 'Alex 1',
        'salary': '$2000',
        'position': 'developer'
      }, {
        'name': 'Leonardo 1',
        'salary': '$2000',
        'position': 'developer'
      }]);

      var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api('#myTable');
      api.row.clear();

      api.draw();

    }, 5000);
  }
});
```

**controllers/application.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  appName: 'Ember Twiddle',
  data1: [{
    'name': 'John Smith',
    'salary': '$2000',
    'position': 'developer'
  }, {
    'name': 'Alex',
    'salary': '$2000',
    'position': 'developer'
  }, {
    'name': 'Leonardo',
    'salary': '$2000',
    'position': 'developer'
  }]
});
```

Comment: Unrelated but I'm trying to access the gitbub and it seems to be down github.com/mfcollins3/ember-datatables. I would recommand you to not incorporate into your project an unmaintained plugin. [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-datatables)

Comment: I agree that it is not maintained. But It is in working condition. I will try for one more day. If didn't work then I will switch to another add-on.

Comment: i wouldn't use this addon either. it's fairly straightforward to implement a sortable table in ember. i would not wrap a jquery plugin for this task. there are all sorts of downsides to this approach

Comment: Use [ember-contextual-table](https://tubitak-bilgem-yte.github.io/ember-contextual-table/#/overview), very simple to use, here its [github](https://github.com/tubitak-bilgem-yte/ember-contextual-table).

Comment: [ember-contextual-table](https://tubitak-bilgem-yte.github.io/ember-contextual-table/#/overview) rocks! (Ok I admit; I'm one of the owners of ember-contextual-table; but nevertheless it will solve the problem of question asker). Some other addons; which can be used; are [ember-table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-table) and [ember-light-table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-light-table)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `TypeError: api.row.clear is not a function.`

Changing from `api.row.clear()` to `api.clear()` is fixing your issue.

Consider avoiding this addon like mentioned in comments.